# How can a Docker Container listen on the same Port like the IDE?

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac

Normally the IDE should tell me, that a port is already in use, if there is a docker container which forwards its port to the same port - for example 8080.

I am using Docker for Mac in version:

```
Client:
 Version:      18.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.37
 Go version:   go1.9.5
 Git commit:   9ee9f40
 Built:        Thu Apr 26 07:13:02 2018
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64
 Experimental: false
 Orchestrator: swarm

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      18.03.1-ce
  API version:  1.37 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.5
  Git commit:   9ee9f40
  Built:        Thu Apr 26 07:22:38 2018
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: true
```

docker ps (summary):

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE       STATUS              PORTS                    
<some-id>           my-app      Up 3 seconds        0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp
```

IDE in Debugging mode (Spring Boot App):

```
...Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
```

When I send a curl request the app from the container sends the response. I know that, because there is a break point in the IDE. When I stop the docker container, the request stops at the break point.

How can these two processes listen on the same port?

Comment: Are you running your IDE and containers on the same host with no VMs involved?

Comment: The IDE and docker for Mac are running on the same Mac book. There is no VM included, but the xhyve VM used by docker for Mac.